# Android DatePickerDialog CalendarView's title Inconsistency

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog, calendarview

I am creating a `DatePickerDialog`, like it's done in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker). However, I am noticing that the `CalendarView`'s title (i.e. "December 2012" as it would be for today) doesn't change immediately when the year is set in the `Spinner`s. I see that the weeks are changed correctly, and I can set the title on the dialog based on the `onSelectedDayChange` callback with the appropriate date (month, month day, year, week day). Furthermore, if the month is changed in the `Spinner`s, then the `CalendarView` is updated immediately. This includes, correctly showing the selected year if the year was changed before the month was changed. And if the `CalendarView` is scrolled to other months the year also gets adjusted to show the correct year.

This seems to imply that the `CalendarView` simply isn't redrawing the title (probably optimization?) when the date is getting set. Am I doing something else wrong? Is there a solution to this? Or is it a bug in the implementation?

Here's my code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    /** Name of the date stored in a {@link Bundle} */
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "key.DatePickerFragment.DATE";

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle icicle) {
        final Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        Time date = arguments == null
                ? TimeMachine.getTimeFromArray(getArguments().getIntArray(KEY_DATE))
                : null;

        if (date == null)
            date = TimeMachine.getToday();

        _dialog_window = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, date.year, date.month, date.monthDay);
        final CalendarView calendar_view = _dialog_window.getDatePicker().getCalendarView();
        calendar_view.setOnDateChangeListener(
                new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView _, int year, int month, int day) {
                        updateTitle(TimeMachine.getTimeFromArray(new int[]{ year, month, day }));
                    }
                }
        );

        // Sets the title
        updateTitle(date);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return _dialog_window;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker _, int year, int month, int day) {
        final Time date = new Time();
        date.set(day, month, year);
    }

    private void updateTitle(Time date) {        
        _dialog_window.setTitle(date.format(" %A,  %B %e, %Y"));
    }

    /** The Dialog window */
    private DatePickerDialog _dialog_window;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as there aren't others coming forth with any other answer, I got around this problem by not enabling the `CalendarView` on the `DatePicker`, and instead making a custom `DialogFragment` that had a numerical date picker and a separate `CalendarView` (actually my own reimplementation based on the real `CalendarView` to allow tweaks to it's display and Otto event bus). Then I can make sure that the `CalendarView` is set each time the numeric date picker is set.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the same issue and submitted a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53875